# How to set opacity for text color in JSPdf

Tags: javascript, angular, jspdf

I am using Jspdf for generate pdf, along with table with multiple records and I want to display watermark text on table but I am not able to set opacity for watermark text color.
How to set opacity to the text color in JSpdf in angular

Answer (score 9):

You can use `setGState()` to set opacity before drawing text, like this:

```
doc.saveGraphicsState();
doc.setGState(new doc.GState({opacity: 0.2}));
doc.text(text, x, y, {align: 'center', baseline: 'middle'})
doc.restoreGraphicsState();
```

Comment: It works! Thanks